# Emulating a RTC in Java

Tags: java, jvm, emulation

A while ago I started writing an emulator of the [IBM 5150 Personal Computer in C#](https://github.com/josterhage/PC-Emulator.git). While I got most of the way done, I never finished it, and now I want to re-write it in Java. One of the technical issues I ran into was how to emulate a 4.77MHz clock tick. I'll send the tick signal through an interface method, most likely each class that needs to act on a clock tick will implement some form of:

```
public interface Clocked {
     void onTick();
}
```

How could I implement this in Java that would allow me to fairly closely emulate the clock behavior and timing I'm looking for?

My current idea is to implement a class that calls onTick() to a set of registered Clocked objects every time a simple count-down timer reaches 1/4_770_000 of a second:

```
public class RTC {
   private List<Clocked> clockedObjects;
   private long nanoSecondsElapsed;
   private final long NS_PER_TICK = 1_000_000_000 / 4_770_000;
   private boolean isRunning;

   // the "how" of initialization isn't important here

   public void startClock() {
      isRunning = true;
      nanoSecondsElapsed = System.nanoTime();
      while(isRunning) {
         if(System.nanoTime() - nanoSecondsElapsed > NS_PER_TICK) {
            clockedObjects.forEach(Clocked::onTick);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Testing on my local system, I see right away that my time resolution varies between 300ns-600ns (with a few iterations taking as long as 6400ns) without any meaningful load on the system, while the resolution of a tick at 4.77MHz is ~209ns.

Is there a way to get a finer grained tick, or possibly a better way to implement this?

Comment: nanoTime() has the most resolution. Its performance depend significantly on the platform.

Comment: Your loop is a spin-loop—it runs constantly, never giving other threads a chance to do any work.  Obviously this a very bad idea, especially for an emulator.  Try using a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()).

Comment: @VGR: thanks for catching that and thanks for the suggestion. I'll probably use your suggestion for testing. I think I'm going to have to implement my original idea: a device driver that hooks the APIC interfaced through JNI.

Comment: Your `nanoSecondsElapsed` variable has a misleading name, as it does not contain elapsed time at all. Further, there’s no reason to make it an instance field instead of a local variable. Then, there’s no update within the loop, so you’re only measuring the time elapsed since the beginning of the loop. Once the time is larger than one tick (after the first tick) it will stay larger forever (well for more than 290 years) so you’re effectively not checking the time at all but just running as fast as you can.

Comment: @Holger Yeah. I renamed it in my local test version, but I'm not using this flow anyway.